# How to enable WCF server side caching?

Tags: .net, wcf, caching

Is it possible without writing your own proxy? I have thought of using an open source proxy but it would only work with http bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're planning to support other transports than HTTP, you'll need to deal with cache yourself.

This not meant to write your own host: you can to implement `IOperationInvoker` as in this sample: [Extending WCF with Custom Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx#S6)